# Gitlab deploy to Kubernetes namespace not allowed

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

Using Gitlab+Kubernetes, how to deploy something to a specific (e.g. **test**) namespace? I've followed the Gitlab doc, but I can't find how to select a specific namespace when deploying.

This `.gitlab-ci.yml` file...

```
stages:
  - deploy
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags: [local]
  environment:
    name: test
    kubernetes:
      namespace: test
  script:
    - kubectl config get-contexts
    - kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml
    - kubectl get pods --namespace deploy-2-test
    - kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml --namespace test
```

...produces this result:

```
  on rap N37D1QxB
Preparing the "shell" executor 00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment 00:00
... [everything fine until here]

Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:00

$ kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME            CLUSTER         AUTHINFO        NAMESPACE
*         gitlab-deploy   gitlab-deploy   gitlab-deploy   deploy-2-test

$ kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment created

$ kubectl get pods --namespace deploy-2-test
NAME                                READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-4lx4s   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-dcpcr   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s

$ kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml --namespace test
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "apps/v1, Resource=deployments", GroupVersionKind: "apps/v1, Kind=Deployment"
Name: "nginx-deployment", Namespace: "test"
from server for: "nginx.yaml": deployments.apps "nginx-deployment" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:deploy-2-test:deploy-2-test-service-account" cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "apps" in the namespace "test"
Cleaning up file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

- Notice that the deployment is done on the *deploy-2-test* namespace, even if the .gitlab-ci.yml file points to the *test* namespace; and if the `--namespace` is included in the deploy command, there's no right to deploy.
- Following the Gitlab doc, I've added the cluster-admin Cluster Role
  to the gitlab ServiceAccount, which should be allmighty...

The nginx deployment is the [classic one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/application/deployment.yaml). How to deploy to the **test** namespace? why and how is the namespace *deploy-2-test* generated?

Comment: Is the gitlab runner self hosted one or shared runner?. You need to provide the runner to access the EKS cluster via the RBAC role also. What I did was I've deployed a self hosted EC2 runner with IAM role configured to access the EKS (AWS Kubernetes) and added the iam role in Kubernetes RBAC spec also

Comment: @Prashanna This is a shared runner. But I think you are missing the point. The objective is to use the Gitlab mechanisms to make the deployment, not just using gitlab running commands to perform tweaked deployments. I've created the Gitlab suggested RBAC role (to grant the gitlab service account subject with the cluster-admin ClusterRole, which is perhaps even excessive).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: just disable the option `GitLab-managed cluster` in the Gitlab cluster definition page.

Excerpt from the output:

```
...
$ kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME            CLUSTER         AUTHINFO        NAMESPACE
*         gitlab-deploy   gitlab-deploy   gitlab-deploy   test

$ kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment created

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-55m6p   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-vbhtc   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          0s
Cleaning up file based variables
Job succeeded
```

Effectively, the `deploy.environment.kubernetes.namespace` is the one defining the final k8s namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but setting the `environment:kubernetes:namespace` setting might not change your current context. It only applies that value to the `KUBE_NAMESPACE` environment variable.

If you want to be sure you can always use `--namespace $KUBE_NAMESPACE` in your scripts. That's what we do too, to prevent any context issues with our scripts.

Comment: As you can see in the OP, `--namespace` **was** used and had no effect. `environment:kubernetes:namespace` **does** change the context. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per the instructions, there's a - kubectl config use-context line missing from your script after     - kubectl config get-contexts. With this in place, --namespace works for me.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me. By default, when you do `kubectl config get-contexts` it returns a context, but it is not being selected by default(you will not see a * under the CURRENT column). Using a `kubectl config use-context YOUR_CONTEXT` will make this context in use, and then the CI would have the privilege to `apply` your YAML files.